# Why do check for UPDATE(<column>) return false?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have created a Trigger in SQL Server:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[TIME_PersonalTagUpdIns] on [dbo].[TIME_PersonalTag] for INSERT,UPDATE as
    if not UPDATE(SyncToTimeTac)
    BEGIN
       update a
          set a.SyncToTimeTac=0x31
          from TIME_PersonalTag a inner join inserted b on a.Ident=b.Ident 
          where a.Erledigt = 0x31
    END
```

Now, when I execute

```
update TIME_PersonalTag set SyncToTimeTac = 0x30
```

the goal is to not execute the Logic in the Trigger. For this, I check at the beginning `if not UPDATE(SyncToTimeTac)` - but the triggerlogic will nevertheless executed when I run the statement above.

I don't see why this happens.

Comment: I don't know this subject but as an opinion, the possible reason may be : there's no an UPDATE statement upto the line of `UPDATE(SyncToTimeTac)`, mightn't be ..?

Comment: @BennoDual why you don't use deleted, inserted tables instead ? like this `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE SyncToTimeTac = 0x30) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted WHERE SyncToTimeTac = 0x30)`

Comment: I can't appear to replicate this problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/938b9/3 . On a different note: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Even if this logic had worked, when firing for `INSERT`, **every** column has been `UPDATE`d and so somethings off here (the trigger as written would never perform any further logic for an insert, so either the logic is wrong or the trigger shouldn't fire for `INSERT`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the trigger logic gets executed even if you specifically update the `SyncToTimeTac`, but I can offer an alternative to the `UPDATE()` function, that is more reliable - since the `UPDATE` function will return true even if the update was not successful:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[TIME_PersonalTagUpdIns] on [dbo].[TIME_PersonalTag] 
FOR INSERT,UPDATE 
AS

   UPDATE a
      SET a.SyncToTimeTac = 0x31
      FROM TIME_PersonalTag AS a 
      INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
          ON a.Ident = i.Ident 
      INNER JOIN deleted AS d
          ON d.Ident = i.Ident
      WHERE a.Erledigt = 0x31
      AND ISNULL(i.SyncToTimeTac, 0x31) = ISNULL(d.SyncToTimeTac, 0x31)
END
```

Now it should set the `SyncToTimeTac` to `0x31` only if the value of that column was not changed.